# Flutter : Creating Widgets on the go for ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code I am trying to make it work but not having much luck.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).adminStructures.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: blue,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: blue,
          title: Text('Select Category'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            isScrollable: true,
            enableFeedback: true,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: [
              for (final structure in Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).adminStructures)
                Tab(text: structure.name),
            ],
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            for (final structure in Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).adminStructures)
              getListOfWidgets(structure)
              
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getListOfWidgets(MyCategory structure) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    List<Answer>? answers = [];
    if (Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).catAndMembers[structure.uid] != null) {
      answers = Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).catAndMembers[structure.uid];
      if (answers != null) {
        answers.forEach((element) {
          widgets.add(ListView(shrinkWrap:true, children: [Text(element.fullName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))]));
        });
      }
    }
    return widgets;
  }
}
```

`catAndMembers is a Map of <String, List<Answer>>`

I get the following error

> 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

I am trying to show answers below each structure category and a blank page under category where there is no answer.

Really could use some help in fixing this, please!

Answer (score 0):

`getListOfWidgets(structure)` returns `List<Widget>`, in this case use spread operator like

```dart
 for (final structure in Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).adminStructures)
                ...Tab(text: structure.name),
```

Also, I prefer including return on method so that it can help to notice reader and IntelliJ. like

```
List<Widget>getListOfWidgets(MyCategory structure)
```

more about [spread-operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator)